# Storing and searching for data from user input (python, no SQL)

Tags: python-3.x, input, collections

I need help getting unstuck. I'm writing a simple program that can store data (name, surname, age and phone number) from user input in memory (just as long as the program is running). Should be able to list them all and search for an individual by name later too. This is what I have in my class so far, but I can't figure out how to progress.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Human(ABC):
     _HumansTotal = 0

@staticmethod
def add_human():
    Human._HumansTotal += 1

def __init__(self, name, surname, age, phone):
    self._name = name
    self._surname = surname
    self._age = age
    self._phone = phone

def list(self, name, surname, age, phone):
    return f"{self._name, self._surname, self._age, self._phone}"
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start like this :

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Humans:
    """A humans data storing class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self._total_humans= 0
        self._humans_data = {}

    # add any human to the class
    def add_human(self, name, surname, age, phone):
        new_human = {
            f'{name}': {
                'surname': surname,
                'age': age,
                'phone': phone
                }
            }
        
        self._humans_data.update(new_human)
        self._total_humans += 1

    # find any addedhuman and their info by name key
    def find_human(self, name):
        human_info = self._humans_data[name]
        return f"name: {name}, surname: {human_info['surname']}, age: {human_info['age']}, phone: {human_info['phone']}"


# testing:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    humans = Humans()
    humans.add_human("toto", "tata", 22, '06660606')

    print(humans.find_human('toto'))
```

output:

```
name: toto, surname: tata, age: 22, phone: 06660606
```

you should also handle the exceptions (in case the human searched isnt yet in the database, etc .. ), typing and commenting your code. This is just a snippet to give you a structural idea, hope it helps!